# why regular class cannot be extended?

Tags: apex, inheritance

I am a extending class with out using abstract or virtual class ,it throwing me the error "non-virtual or non-abstract classes cannot be extended". why regular classes cannot be extended in apex.

```
global class new1 {
    global static void write() {
        system.debug('hellor');
    }
}
```

Extended Class:

```
global class tow extends new1 {
    global static void newwrite(); {
        system.debug('hellroe');
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your code snippet too please.

Comment: global class new1
{
global static void write()
{
system.debug('hellor');
}
}

Comment: global class tow extends new1
{
global static void newwrite();
{
system.debug('hellroe');
}}

Comment: Mahesh, please always try to keep all relevant info in the question itself. You can always update it, i've taken the liberty to do that for you in this event.

Comment: @mahesh , if you feel satisfied with the answers, please accept one of them to help the others to find the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just one of two possible approaches. For example, in C# you can derive from superclass and there's no need to mark it anyhow. You can - on the other hand - mark class as `sealed` (equivalent to `final` in apex, which is default) to prevent inheritance. I don't think there could be any advantage of any of these approaches.

Answer (score 1):

To put it in simple words that's the way APEX is designed. You can go through this [blog](https://medium.com/elevate-salesforce/apex-classes-and-java-classes-work-quite-similar-but-there-are-some-differences-98c6c7b9c217) to discuss the difference between APEX and JAVA inheritance declarations.